# clone datable to another datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

There is a dataTable A with some cloumns containing DateTime value, how do I clone A to another dataTable B, only preserve the Date of A's DateTime column? The following code will preserve all the trailing zeros like **20/05/2015 00:00:00**, is there a way to truncate them? Thanks.

```
foreach (DataColumn col in A.Columns) 
{
  if (col.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
  {
    B.Columns[col.ColumnName].DataType = typeof(string);
  }
}
foreach (DataRow row in A.Rows) 
{
  B.ImportRow(row);
}
```

Comment: You can format a `DateTime` as a `string` in whatever format you'd like, for example `dateTimeValue.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");` or `dateTimeValue.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");` would be more appropriate for your specific situation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a new datatable B
2. Copy all columns that are of type datetime.Import all rows from A to B
3. Iterate through the B datatable rows & columns and format the date

   ```
    DataTable B = new DataTable();

    foreach (DataRow row in A.Rows)
    {
         foreach (DataColumn col in A.Columns)
         {
               if (col.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
                    B.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName);
         }
         B.ImportRow(row);
    }
    foreach (DataRow row in B.Rows)
    {
         foreach (DataColumn col in B.Columns)
         {
              //Console.WriteLine("Before {0}:",row[col.ColumnName]);
              row[col.ColumnName] = DateTime.Parse(row[col.ColumnName].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
              //Console.WriteLine("After {0}:", row[col.ColumnName]);
         }
    }
   ```

[image: Output]

Comment: I got an error saying {"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."} when executed to row[col.ColumnName] = DateTime.Parse(String.Format("{0}:dd/MM/yyyy",row[col.ColumnName]));

Comment: @Yan Try DateTime.Parse(String.Format("{0}:dd/MM/yyyy",row[col.ColumnName].ToString()))

Comment: Still the same error when I added the toString() method to row[col.ColumnName]

Comment: I think the problem is when you try to parse the string, it's not formatted asdd/MM/yyyy, but dd/MM/yyyy hh/mm/ss, so it's not recognized as a valid datetime

Comment: @Yan The issue is after your format the column type datetime doesn't recognize the string as valid datetime.I've modifed the code to handle it in a different way.Check it out.It should work when you don't specify the column type for the new datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the format of the numbers does not change or does the special characters. You can create a regex and assign that to a variable, like so:

```
// Regex match
var regexExp = /(^\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/;
```